# Compare reference two character with same value in Java

Tags: java, memory, jvm

We know that the Runtime Constant Pool in Java stores the following literals:
1) Integer 2) Long 3) Float 4) Double 5) String . Hence, where are the Boolean Literals and Character Literals stored??

Example:

```
Character c1 = 'a';
Character c2 = 'a';
System.out.println(c1==c2); //prints true
```

Since `==` compares references, does c1 and c2 share the same reference? (=Note that these literals are created such that they are the objects of the respective Primitive Wrapper Classes.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, c1 and c2 share same object in heap so the comparison will be true. This is Java cache mechanism. All characters, integers that value in range -127 .. 127 will be cached. So Java will get cached value instead creating new one. That's why both objects share same references.

```
Character c1 = 'a';
Character c2 = 'a';  
Character c3 = new Character('a');  // force Java creates new object in heap 
System.out.println(c1 == c2); -> true 
System.out.println(c1 == c3); -> false
```

Here is another example for the same reason:

```
Integer i1 = 127;
Integer i2 = 127;
System.out.println(i1 == i2);  // true
Integer i3 = 1000;
Integer i4 = 1000;
System.out.println(i3 == i4); // false, out of cache range
```

You will meet another example for string, but on different mechanism:

```
String s1 = "stack";
String s2 = "stack";
String s3 = new String("stack");
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true
System.out.println(s1 == s3); // false
```

All java string when creating will be allocated and stored in `String Pool`. When you create new string (in case of s2), Java will search in `String pool` if this string is already allocated somewhere or not. In case s3, we say to Java: "Hi, Java, please always create new one for me".

Summary, when comparing two objects, using `compareTo` method, when compare two primitive, you can use `==` operator. (just remind you old Java class).

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 2):

> We know that the Runtime Constant Pool in Java stores the following literals: 1) Integer 2) Long 3) Float 4) Double 5) String .

Actually, that is not quite correct.  A correct statement is that *in practice* there is a separate runtime pool for autoboxed values for each of the types `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer` and `Long`.

These pools are NOT for *literals* ... because literals of the wrapper types do not exist<sup>1</sup>.  The Java literals for these types are values of primitive types.  (And in fact, there are no distinct literals at all for types `byte` or `short` ... according to the JLS.)

There are NOT autoboxing pools for `Float` and `Double`, despite what the javadocs for the respective `valueOf` methods seem to imply.  The JLS does not require autobox caching for `Float` and `Double`, and the libraries do not implement it (at least in Java 6, 7, 8).

The other thing to note is that not all values produced by autoboxing will be in the respective pools.  For instance, (by default) only `Integer` caches the values for -128 through +127.

> Hence, where are the Boolean Literals and Character Literals stored?

The answer follows from the above:

- There are no literals of type `Boolean` and `Character`.
- Instances of `Boolean` and `Character` created by autoboxing *may* come out of the respective autoboxing pools.

And for your example:

> Since == compares references, does c1 and c2 share the same reference?

That is correct.  And it illustrates the previous point.  The autoboxing pool for `Character` is required (by the JLS) to cache `'\u0000'` through `'\u007f'`.

---

Note that I left out `String`.  The `String` pool is different because it is (primarily) for string literals.  On the other hand, autoboxing is not defined for string values ... because string values don't have to contend with the primitive versus wrapper dichotomy.

---

<sup>1 - Sorry for being pedantic, but if you want to really understand these things and talk coherently to other people about them, it is essential to use the correct Java-specific terminology.  To be strictly correct, a Literal is something that appears in the >>source code<< of a program.  At runtime, the corresponding thing is a Value.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
Character c1 = 'a';
Character c2 = 'a';
```

as same as

```
Character c1 = 'a';
Character c2 = c1;
```

Both references pointing to the same object.In the second case that I created, c2 referring to c1, where c1 is also a reference variable that's pointing to the object `'a'`.

More explanation about reference variables can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html).

Also to be more precise, you are creating two reference variables in the Stack memory, nominally c1 and c2 but both of them pointing to the same object in the heap memory!

Comment: The person who disliked this: Can you kindly explain what I said wrong?

Comment: Not true. The `char` literal gets autoboxed into separate `Character` class instances on each line. Seeing as `Character` instances are immutable, they are affectively "the same" in usage, but occupy different places in memory.

Comment: It may not be guaranteed that the JVM implementation being used is sophisticated enough to cache boxed instances of easily countable primitives (i.e. char and boolean). So what you're saying isn't necessarily wrong, it just isn't necessarily always correct. Regardless, you're not answering the question. Change `Character` to `Long` in your example, and it's unlikely what you said will hold true anymore. I'm not the one who downvoted you ;)

Comment: @ Ownaginatious but when you change `Character` to `Long` then you also need to define long objects, in this case `new Long(sth)` or just a long premitive long. Then you can decide if both references pointing to same object or not. Just changing to Long but keeping `'a'` will anyway give a compiler error.

Comment: @Ownaginatious You are mistaken. Autoboxing uses `Character.valueOf()`, which has well-specified pooling semantics. Java guarantees that the statements made in this answer are correct.

Comment: @EJB thanks, didn't know that caching behaviour was defined for Character, Boolean, and Integer for -127 to 127. Issue I had with this answer was the lack of explanation of the caching behaviour, which is what OP was asking about. Seems like it's been fixed though.

Comment: @Ownaginatious The issue you had with this answer was that it relied on a specification that you explicitly asserted did not exist. I can't see anything the edit history that constitutes 'fixing' that, not that it was necessary in the first place.